# Inbuilt jQuery Pagination and sorting in cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, pagination

Is there inbuilt jQuery pagination and sorting available in cakephp like that of jQuery.
I couldnt find relevant matter on the NET.
Kindly refer to me.

Regards
Himanshu Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Withg built in library:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1231/Pagination

Else look at:
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/daphonz/2008/05/03/easy-ajax-pagination-using-jquery

Hope it helps :)